# Pointers and data types

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following question.

Given that a pointer holds the value of a memory address, why is it permitted to add an integer
data type value to a pointer variable but not a double data type?

My thoughts: Is it because we assume that the pointer is an int as well, or maybe because if we add a double will increase its length?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What would `ptr+1.1` mean? You can't address subbytes. If you want to add a double to a pointer, you can always do it by casting it to an integer first. Admittedly, the language could do the cast for you, but it chooses not to.

Comment: If you have a `const char* text = "abc"` then `*(text+1) == 'b'`, but what character do you expect at `*(text+ 1.5)` ?

Comment: Adding integers to pointers is called *pointer arithmetic*, and is the basis of all array indexing. For example, for any array *or pointer* `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(a + i)`. Now, as mentioned, what would it mean by adding a fraction to a pointer? You can't address bits or parts of a memory cell.

Comment: I think is question is to add for instance a long or long long to a pointer,  supposing long/long long have 64 bits while int has 32 bits, not a float/double

Comment: You can add an integer to your home address and get the address of someone else, but not 1.3. Isn’t this strange?

Answer (score 1):

You almost answered your question yourself: a pointer is a memory address. A memory address is an integer. You can add integers to integers and get integers as a result. Adding a float to an integer gives you a float, which cannot be used as a memory address.

For example, `char *x = 0;` is the address of a single byte; What would `char *y = 0.5;` mean? A byte that's somehow made up of the second half of the byte at address 0 and the first half of the byte at address 1?? This may make sense, but what about `char *x = 3.1415926;` or any similar floating-point number??

Comment: "which cannot be used as a memory address" I think "cannot" is not a right term here. It does not make sense so not defined.

Comment: @Slava, I think it's both: it doesn't make sense, _and_ one physically cannot address parts of bytes.

Comment: If the array elements are each 4 bytes then adding 0.25 to a pointer could access a specific byte, however the languages chooses not to humor the insane.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add a double* (pointer) to an int* (pointer) via the conventions of C. A pointer holds a value of a memory address ["stores/points to the address of another variable"] that value in essence is determined by its type in this case int(4 byte-block of memory if I recall). A double is a double-precision, 64-bit floating-point data type. Just can't do it from the most "hardware" of levels.

Comment: "int(4 bit-block of memory if I recall)" - an `int` is typically 4 _bytes_ long

Answer (score 0):

> My thoughts: Is it because we assume that the pointer is an int as well, or maybe because if we add a double will increase its length?

If you look to [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) it says:

> Certain addition, subtraction, increment, and decrement operators are defined for **pointers to elements of arrays**: such pointers satisfy the LegacyRandomAccessIterator requirements and allow the C++ library algorithms to work with raw arrays.

(emphasis is mine) and you should remember that:

```
*(ptr + 1)
```

is equal to:

```
ptr[1]
```

and indexes for arrays are integers so language does not define operations on pointers with floating point operands as that does not make any sense.